# ScrollElasticsearchHttp processor Count in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, elasticsearch-5

Hi am trying to take simple count of "ScrollElasticsearchHttp" processor in nifi. and using QueryRecord after this processor. I have created one new variable and using below Sql

```
             "select count(1) from FLOFILE"
```

I am expecting result.count value 10000 which is my record count but its always showing record.count value 1.

can someone suggest how should I take count of this ScrollElasticsearchHttp flow.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of **ScrollElasticsearchHttp** [processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-elasticsearch-nar/1.16.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.ScrollElasticsearchHttp/):

> Each page of results is returned, wrapped in a JSON object like so: { "hits" : [ , ,  ] }.

Firstly use a **EvaluateJsonPath** processor:

- `Destination`: `flowfile-content`
- `Return Type`: `auto-detect`
- `hits` (dynamic): `$.hits`

Then use a **QueryRecord** processor:

- `count`: `SELECT COUNT(1) AS COUNT FROM FLOWFILE`